# Change jQuery UI Dialog box to Fancybox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, fancybox-2

I want to change jQuery UI dialog box alert message to display using Fancybox 2. However, I couldn't figure out how to do this. pls advise.

Here is the original script which does some validation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                            $('#Continue').click(function () {
                                //terms of services
                                var pi = document.getElementById("term").innerHTML;
                                var termOfServiceOk = true;
                                if (pi == "True") {

                                    if (!$('#termsofservice').is(':checked')) {
                                        $("#terms-of-service-warning-box").dialog();
                                        termOfServiceOk = false;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        ConfirmOrder.save()
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    ConfirmOrder.save()
                                }

                            });
                        });
```

Pls advise how I can hook a Fancybox 2 to display an inline content inplace of dialog box.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `#terms-of-service-warning-box` contents is what you want to display in fancybox, then replace

```
$("#terms-of-service-warning-box").dialog();
```

by

```
$.fancybox("#terms-of-service-warning-box");
```

like in :

```
....
if (pi == "True") {
    if (!$('#termsofservice').is(':checked')) {
        //$("#terms-of-service-warning-box").dialog();
        $.fancybox("#terms-of-service-warning-box");
        termOfServiceOk = false;
    } else {
....
```

It's assumed that you have properly loaded the fancybox js and css files.